# mlogit package in R error column name "" cannot match any column

Tags: r, mlogit

I am using the mlogit package in R and trying to run mlogit on the Train dataset that is available in the package. Here is my code:

```
mlogit.data(Train,shape='wide',choice = "choice", varying = 4:11, sep = "",alt.levels = c(1,2), id = "id")
```

I get the following error:

> Error in `[<-.data.frame`(`*tmp*`, , v.names, value = c(2400, 2400,
> 2400,  :    column name "" cannot match any column In addition:
> Warning message: In dfidx::dfidx(data = data, dfa$idx, drop.index =
> dfa$drop.index,  :   the levels shouldn't be provided with a data set
> in wide format

I am not sure where is the mistake here.

Comment: same. not sure what the issue is

Answer (score 0):

Try changing the `sep` param:

```
mlogit.data(Train, shape = 'wide', choice="choice",
                 varying=4:11, sep="_", id = "id")
```

I believe the dataset has changed since the example was created. The separator should be the underscore